# Jquery ID Attribute Contains With Selector and Variable

Tags: jquery, selector, contains

I would like to search for an image ID that contains a value AND a variable.

I need the below script to be something like $("[id*='MYVALUE'+x]") but that does not work.

```
for (x=0; x< imageList.length; x++) 
    {

    var imageSRC = imageList[x];

    //need this to be MYVALUE + the X val
    //search for IDs that contain MYVALUE + X
    $("[id*='MYVALUE']").attr('src', 'images/'+imageSRC);

};

<!-- These images are replaced with images from the array imageList-->
<img id="dkj958-MYVALUE0" src="images/imageplaceholder" />
<img id="mypage-MYVALUE1" src="images/imageplaceholder" />
<img id="onanotherpage-MYVALUE2-suffix" src="images/imageplaceholder" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/w2UUg/2/

```
$('[id*="MYVALUE' + x + '"]').attr('src', 'images/'+imageSRC);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("[id*='MYVALUE" + x + "']")
```

Should do what you want. Sorry this is really badly formatted, I'm attempting to type on a mobile.

Comment: Thanks, I would give you extra points for typing on a mobile. The quotes were backwards tho. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').filter(function () {
    return this.id.match(/myvalue\d+/i);
}).attr('src', 'images/' + imageSRC);
```